# Show 3D canvas in React THREE js workspace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have created a workspace with react-three and wants to show a canvas in 3D, I already developed 2D canvas which has both width and depth, but i need it to be 3D with height as well for my measurements.

Tried developing a 2D default canvas but failed to make it 3D and wants to make it 3D, Here is my code.

```
const VoxelPainter = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const isRotatingRef = useRef(false); // Store rotation state in a ref
  let [cubeCount, setCubeCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let camera, scene, renderer;
    let plane;
    let pointer, raycaster, isShiftDown = false;
    let rollOverMesh, rollOverMaterial;
    let cubeGeo, cubeMaterial;
    const objects = [];

    function init() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
      camera.position.set(500, 800, 1300);
      camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

     // Roll-over helpers
     const rollOverGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
     rollOverMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true });
     rollOverMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rollOverGeo, rollOverMaterial);
     scene.add(rollOverMesh);

     // Cubes
     const map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('src/sun.png');
     map.flipY = false;
     map.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace; 
     map.anisotropy = 16; 
     cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
     cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xfeb74c, map: map });
     
     
     // Grid
     const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(1000, 20);
     scene.add(gridHelper);

    

     raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
     pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

     const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000);
     geometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

     plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ visible: false }));
     scene.add(plane);
     objects.push(plane);

   }

    function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      render();
    }

    function onPointerMove(event) {
      pointer.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
      raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
      const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        const intersect = intersects[0];
        rollOverMesh.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
        rollOverMesh.position.divideScalar(50).floor().multiplyScalar(50).addScalar(25);
        render();
      }
    }

    function onPointerDown(event) {
      pointer.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
      raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
      const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        const intersect = intersects[0];

        // Delete cube
        if (isShiftDown) {
          if (intersect.object !== plane) {
            scene.remove(intersect.object);
            objects.splice(objects.indexOf(intersect.object), 1);
            setCubeCount(--cubeCount);
            console.log('cube count is --> ' + cubeCount);
          }
        }
        // Create cube
        else {
          //axis x,y,z
          var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
           scene.add(axesHelper);
          console.log('here');
          
          const voxel = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMaterial);
          voxel.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
          voxel.position.divideScalar(50).floor().multiplyScalar(50).addScalar(25);
          scene.add(voxel,axesHelper);
          objects.push(voxel,axesHelper);
          setCubeCount(cubeCount++);
          console.log('cube count is --> ' + cubeCount);

        }
        render();
      }
    }

    function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 16:
          isShiftDown = true;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    function onDocumentKeyUp(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 16:
          isShiftDown = false;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    function render() {
      if (isRotatingRef.current) { // Check rotation state from ref
        scene.rotation.y += 0.005;
      }
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    init();
    render();

    return () => {
      // Clean up Three.js resources if needed
      cubeMaterial.dispose();
      cubeGeo.dispose();
      renderer.dispose();
    };
  }, []); // No dependencies for this effect

  const handleToggleRotation = () => {
    isRotatingRef.current = !isRotatingRef.current; // Toggle rotation state in the ref
  };

  const buttonStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '10px',
    left: '10px',
    zIndex: '1',
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>CubeCount: {cubeCount}</div>
      <div ref={containerRef} />
      <button onClick={handleToggleRotation} style={buttonStyle}>
        Toggle Rotation
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VoxelPainter;
```